# How to translate "knowledge" as in "general understanding or familiarity" in this case?

Tags: translation

Which translation of "knowledge" would fit into the following sentence?

> They have the resources, but do they have the knowledge?

I'm looking for a literal translation, not an idiom or restructuring.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I generally prefer German words, I'd actually say this:

> Sie haben die Ressourcen, aber haben sie auch das [nötige] Know-how?

At least in my field, both words are not unheard of in this context.

There are alternatives to "Know-how" like *Wissen* or *Kenntnisse*, but especially in a business context, *Know-how* might be more precise.

*Erfahrung* may also work as a replacement to *Know-how*, but is not exactly the same.

Edit: According to Duden, the correct spelling is either *Know-how* or *Knowhow*. Didn't know that before.

Comment: +1: Sometimes the best German word is an English loanword.

Answer (score 5):

I would translate it to `Kompetenz`.

Answer (score 3):

> They have the resources, but do they have the knowledge?

Sie haben die Möglichkeit, aber haben sie 
 * die Expertise?
 * das Fachwissen? (das (technische) Wissen, das Expertenwissen) 
 * die Kompetenz? (copy from 0x6d64) 
 * das Knowhow? (OregonGhost)
 * die Erfahrung? (s.o.)

Abhängig vom Kontext. Bei Pilzesammlern die einen Korb und ein Messer haben eher Erfahrung, bei Außerirdischen, die ein Weltraumschiff gekapert haben Expertise od. technisches Wissen, bei ambitionierten Heimwerkern oder Autoschraubern Knowhow.

Comment: Danke. In diesem Beispiel ist es bei eine Waage zu Hause bauen.

Comment: @Tim Sie haben das Werkzeug, aber haben sie auch das Können?

Comment: 'Können' could in this case be interpreted as 'Geschicklichkeit' (that would be my problem :) ) - I would go with the 'Knowhow' or just 'Wissen'.